# How to write letters with ASCII characters?

Tags: java, character, letter, ascii-art

The title may be confusing, but an example will clarify:

User type a string of characters: `ab`.

The console displays (in theory):

[image: example]

But all I can do is to display:

[image: actual display]

How can I display the text like in the example?

This are the classes:

Main:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaractereDinAlteCaractereMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Caractere ochei = new Caractere();

        System.out.println("Introduceti caractere: "); //insert characters
        String caracter = userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < caracter.length(); i++) {
            ochei.litera(caracter.substring(i, i + 1));
            System.out.println(ochei.getCaracter());
        }
    }
}
```

Caractere:

```java
public class Caractere {
    private String caracter;

    public String getCaracter() {
        return caracter;
    }

    public String litera(String userInput) {
        switch (userInput) {
            case "A":
                caracter = "     *     \n" +
                           "    * *    \n" +
                           "   *****   \n" +
                           "  *     *  \n" +
                           " *       * \n";
                break;
            case "B":
                caracter = " *****  \n" +
                           " *    * \n" +
                           " ****** \n" +
                           " *    * \n" +
                           " *****  \n";
                break;
            case "C":
        }
        return caracter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `\n` so it looks like this at the end of the print its printing a new line placing the `B` on the line below it.

```java
caracter = " *     \n" +
       "    * *    \n" +
       "   *****   \n" +
       "  *     *  \n" +
       " *       * ";
```